# Can you view an aggregate changeset in git? If so, how?

Tags: git, diff

In Subversion you can specify a range of versions to get an aggregate view of a series of commits.  Is this possible in git?  If so, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass ranges of revisions using the .. (and ...) operator.

```
git diff 6d0918...HEAD
```

instead of giving (abbreviated) SHA hashes, you can also denote revisions relative to branches and tags:

```
git diff HEAD~4 # shows the diff from the last four commits to the current one
```

Have a look at the chapter "Specifying Revisions" in the [git-rev-parse manual page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html)